# How can I see the current state of a file buffer?

Tags: ruby, file, io, buffer

I want to gain some insight into how Ruby manages file buffering. I looked elsewhere for the answers, but I guess I'm not asking the right questions.

In an IRB session I opened a file for reading:

```
f = File.open('somefile.txt', 'r')
```

Using this command:

```
puts f.gets
```

prints out the first line of `somefile.txt`. If I repeat the `puts f.gets` command, I get the second line, and so on.

My questions are:

1. Is the file buffer being altered by `gets`?
2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, then is there any way to see all the lines that still remain in the buffer?
3. If the answer to question 2 is no, then I'm assuming that `gets` has some record of the last line of the file that it read. Is there any way to find out the value of this line index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.lineno` will give you the current line number
`f.pos` will give you the current offset in bytes